# How to name ether with ketone and carboxyl groups?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, carbonyl-compounds, ethers

Carboxylic acid is the main functional group due to higher priority, but since it's an ether, what's the proper way to name the following compound?

[image: Structural formula of ether with ketone and carboxyl groups]

My attempt: **2-(1-methyl oxo propyl ether) ethanoic acid**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already found out that the carboxylic acid group is the principal characteristic group. Therefore, the ether group has to be expressed as a prefix. The corresponding rule in *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)*) reads as follows.

> **P-63.2.2.1.1** Substituent prefix names for $\ce{R'-O-{}}$ groups are formed by concatenation, i.e., by adding the prefix ‘oxy’ to the substituent prefix name for the group $\ce{R'}$. These compound prefixes require the numerical multiplying prefixes ‘bis’, ‘tris’, etc.

In this case, the substituent prefix name for the $\ce{R'-{}}$ group is 3-oxobutan-2-yl and thus the substituent prefix name for the $\ce{R'-O-{}}$ group is (3-oxobutan-2-yl)oxy. Therefore, the complete name for the compound that is given in the question is **[(3-oxobutan-2-yl)oxy]acetic acid.**

[image: [(3-oxobutan-2-yl)oxy]acetic acid]

Note that locants are omitted for parent compounds when all substitutable hydrogen atoms have the same locant. Therefore, the preferred IUPAC name is [(3-oxobutan-2-yl)oxy]acetic acid and not 2-[(3-oxobutan-2-yl)oxy]acetic acid.

Comment: Thanks but can you just explain 1) why did you add "2-yl" and 2) is it 3 oxo instead of 2 oxo because you went lower numbering to the location of point where the ether connects

Comment: @Chuck butan-2-yl is an alkanyl-type substituent group with the free valence at position 2, not to be confused with the alkyl-type substituent group butyl with the free valence at position 1. It's 3-oxobutan-2-yl and not "2-oxobutan-3-yl" because the free valence gets a low locant first.